# Azure proxy to intranet hosted ASP.net/IIS website

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, kerberos

I have an intranet hosted asp.net/IISv10/windows 2016 website using windows authentication that I am trying to expose to the internet using an Azure proxy.

The current approach is to use kerberos to pass credentials to IIS from Azure. The Azure AD is synchronized with the Domain AD.  We are currently still getting a second windows challenge popup after the Azure authentication is complete. I have done a lot of reading on the issue and I am still actively troubleshooting, but this setup seems very tricky to get working.

My question is: Is Kerberos the best choice for authentication in this scenario? Are other forms of authentication available in the Azure Proxy an easier approach?

Update:  We managed to get the Kerberos working, the issue turned out to be two fold. The first was a typo which messed everything up. Once this was fixed we got a "bad gateway" error that we were able to debug  quickly.
We had set the delegation settings for the App Proxy connector server (xxxxx), for the “Trust this computer for delegation to specified servers only” option, We had the “Use Kerberos only” option selected. The documentation actually says to change it to the “Use any authentication protocol” option. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to Azure Application Proxy, it works with:

- Web applications that use [Integrated Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-with-kcd) for
  authentication
- Web applications that use form-based or [header-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-with-ping-access)
  access
- Web APIs that you want to expose to rich applications on different devices
- Applications hosted behind a [Remote Desktop Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-integrate-with-remote-desktop-services)
- Rich client apps that are integrated with the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL)

Application Proxy supports single sign-on. For more information on supported methods, see Choosing a [single sign-on method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on#choosing-a-single-sign-on-method).

Documentation reference:

[Remote access to on-premises applications through Azure AD Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy)

[Kerberos Constrained Delegation for Single Sign-on to your apps with Application Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-with-kcd)

Hope above information helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. We finally got it working. I will update the post.